# Why does my app crash when I add an row to the table view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm adding a row like this, when a button is pressed. It must be the very first row in the first section:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

I don't call anything else here. No -reloadData. I keep getting this:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The
>   number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (6)
>   must be equal to the number of rows
>   contained in that section before the
>   update (6), plus or minus the number
>   of rows inserted or deleted from that
>   section (1 inserted, 0 deleted).'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you must insert a row into your data source as well as telling the tableView to animate the new row.  In your code (that you haven't posted) you probably have a call to `numberOfRowsInSection`.  At the time of this `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` call, it should be returning 7 (because you are adding one) but instead it is returning 6.